# How to update all git commits from a specific author email address and update in bulk to a new email address?

Tags: bash, git, github, version-control, command-line-interface

Is there a way to update all Git commits in the log where commits from an author of user123@oldemail.com can be bulk replaced with user123@newemail.com?

There are other posts on Stackoverflow with specific commit revision or a list of commit ids to revise but the difference here is if I can find all commits with old email and replace all commits with new email in one bulk action without looking up 1000s of commit IDs.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot with very wide consequences of breaking/rewriting history., if you replace the author, it means replacing the whole commits hash with a new hash. It will have very negative consequences when someone started working on a fork of an old hash, and it has been replaced with a new hash because of author's email editing.

Comment: There're two answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182/7976758 using `git filter-branch` and `git filter-repo`, they certainly do exactly what you need. Any problem with those? Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+email+multiple+commits

Comment: Instead, [add a `.mailmap` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap) that ties the old emails to the new.